# Does anyone know what is the characters means (丁財貴寿)?

Tags: meaning, characters, character-identification

Does anyone know what is written on the image? I tried to find out what is it, and got 丁財貴寿 (丁财贵寿), but not quite sure enough. I tried to find the meaning of the words but seems can't find it or I don't understand what is being written there. When I tried to search with the traditional hanzi, there is a lot of information provided in Japanese, but when use the simplified one, there is a lot of information provided in Chinese, but I can't get the meaning.

If the characters is read: 丁财贵寿 (dīngcáiguìshòu), what does it means? And, does somebody knows why it is read orderly from top, bottom, right and finally left? Thanks.

[image: 丁財貴寿]

Comment: The characters you get are correct.

Comment: @fefe: I see, but I can't find out the meaning of the characters..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are fengshui related words, each having its own meaning:

- 丁 - 催旺人丁 (brings male offspring)
- 財 - 興旺財源 (brings fortune)
- 貴 - 平安富貴 (brings peace and wealth)
- 壽 - 健康長壽 (brings health and longevity)

Quoted from [this article](http://zewei.com/Fengshui/fengshuiarticle08.htm):

> 玄空學說是利用五行形理相生的關係，去令一宅之中充滿生生不息的氣機。
>
> 風水學中的「催旺人丁、興旺財源、人口平安富貴及健康長壽」等等目的，簡稱為「丁財貴壽」等方法，便是依五行相生之理而建立的。

The purpose of the inscription may be to counter (剋) some negative elements (煞) in the house.

Comment: Note 丁 is not just offspring, but MALE offspring -- as non-PC as that may be...

Comment: @dda, I agree with you. 添丁 to 传宗接代 (add a son to carry on the family lineage).

Answer (score 4):

- 丁: Male child
- 財: Riches
- 貴: Honor
- 寿: Longevity

It's a good fortune sentence. The order (which appears normally on coins, the shape of which this reproduces), is North South East West.

Comment: Actually 貴 means valuable or expensive. Doesn't have anything to do with honour at all.

Comment: You have a very narrow, 20th century understanding... http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/226/ Explain words like 貴族 if 貴 only meant "expensive"... Ridiculous....

Comment: Ok, please calm down here. I take your point that it doesn't just mean valuable. However, there is a difference between honour derived from being part of the nobility and honour derived from doing respectable deeds. Nobility is inherently inseparable from wealth and that's what 貴 means here. It's the inherent reputation or honour if you will derived from affluence and high social ranking. I guess that's where I got confused, because honour to me is only gained through good deeds, not the inherited type bestowed upon you by wealth and position.

Comment: By the way, I did give you a +1, so again no need to get abrasive.